# How to adjust the height of the header of a tableview in swift?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, autolayout

I have a UITableViewController. This table view has an header view.
I use main.storyboard with autolayout to set my controller.

In my main.storyboard, for w:Any h:Any, the preview of my view controller is set with the default size 600x600. Inside, my header view is set to 600x200.

In my header view, I have an imageView set to the Aspect Fill mode:

[image: main.storyboard]

The constraints :

[image: constraints]

In the assets, my image has @2x and @3x sizes.

- header-image@2x.png -> 750x498
- header-image@3x.png -> 1242x825

When I compile, in the simulator I obtain for iPhone 5:

[image: IPH5]

For iPhone 6:

[image: IPH6]

For iPhone 6+:

[image: IPH6+]

- For the iPhone 5, the image starts below the status bar. I don't
  understand why?
- For the iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+, the image crops the first cell of my table view. And the top of the image isn't adjust with the top of the view.

I don't know how to adjust the height of the tableHeaderView to the height of my image, because this height depends on the device.

I have tried to set programmatically the frame of the header, in vain:

```
 var frame:CGRect!
 frame.size.width = self.bgHeaderImageView.image?.size.width
 frame.size.height = self.bgHeaderImageView.image?.size.height
 self.tableView.tableHeaderView?.frame = frame
```

I got 2 errors : "Value optional type CGFloat? not unwrapped"

And if I correct with

```
 var frame:CGRect!
 frame.size.width = self.bgHeaderImageView.image?.size.width!
 frame.size.height = self.bgHeaderImageView.image?.size.height!
 self.tableView.tableHeaderView?.frame = frame
```

I got 2 errors : "Operand of postfix ! should have optional type"

Is it to possible to adjust the size in the storyboard directly and not programmatically ?

I'm probably missing something here...

Answer (score 4):

The UITableView tableHeaderView has no option for aspect ratio and autolayout usage of the tableHeaderView is limited in InterfaceBuilder. There are many ways to achieve a dynamic height of the tableHeaderView. If you want to have a tableHeaderView height based on the ratio of a header image you can use:

```
let width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
self.height = (width/640) * 209 //calculate new height
self.tableView.tableHeaderView?.frame.size = CGSize(width: self.tableView.tableHeaderView!.frame.size.width, height: self.height)
```

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution, it's not very clean, but it works.

```
  var kTableHeaderHeight:CGFloat! //expected height of the header tableview

  var image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "my-image")!

  var frame:CGRect!=self.tableView.tableHeaderView?.frame
  if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width <= 320 { //iPhone 5 and less
      frame.size.width = 320
      frame.size.height = 212
   } else { //iPhone 6 @2x and iPhone 6+ @3x
      frame.size.width = image.size.width
      frame.size.height = image.size.height
   }
   self.tableView.tableHeaderView?.frame = frame
```

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution! you helped me with a similar problem, which I want to share just in case someone else experienced it: instead of an uiimageView as background I have a uisearchbar and uibuttons and the height of the tableHeaderView (and tableFooterView as well) would be way to big and stretch over the whole screen height. I couldn't believe there was no possibility in Interface Builder to fix that, or that this error occured in the first place - to me this seems like a bug in the SDK and setting the frame explicitly in viewDidLoad solved it. (iOS 8.2 & XCode 6.2 & OS X 10.9.5)

Comment: this is terrible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

And this too

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if section == 0
    {
        return 1
    }
    else
    {
        return 40; // your other headers height value
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    if section == 0
    {
        // Note CGFloat.min for swift
        // For Objective-c CGFLOAT_MIN
        let headerView = UIView.init(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, CGFloat.min))
        return headerView
    }
    else
    { 
        // Construct your other headers here 
        return UIView()
    }
}
```